# Reinitializing an Array is creating a segfault?

Tags: c, memory-management, initialization, segmentation-fault

I am running breadth first search and bellman ford algorithms on large sets of graph data in the format (u, v, weight) from an input file.

I initialize in the breadth first search, that all vertex's should be marked 0 for unvisited.

Later in the program, since I am calling BFS after every time I add an edge, rather than at the end of the program all together (it's part of a research project on bellman ford and BFS even though it doesn't quite make sense) I reinitialize the vertex array to unvisited.

However, I am getting a segmentation fault when I run larger sets it seems when I reinitialize the vertex array. I make the assumption about larger sets because I have a few smaller sets of test data going from 8 vertices, to 10, then at 100 and larger it fails.

Here is how I initialize at the very beginning of the program:

```
for(i=0;i<numberVertices;i++)
{
    vertexArray[i].v = i+1;
    vertexArray[i].adj = NULL;
    vertexArray[i].marked = 0;
    if(i==0)
    {
        vertexArray[i].weight = 0;
    }
    else{
        vertexArray[i].weight = 10000;
    }
}
```

And here is how I reinitialize at the end of a while loop set to break when it reaches the end of the file directly after BFS finishes:

```
BFS(q, u)
for(i=0;i<numberVertices;i++)
{
    vertexArray[i].marked = 0;
}
```

Like I said it seems to work for smaller data sets, but I do not understand why when I reinitialize it seems to seg fault.

Please let me know your thoughts and suggestions!

Valgrind Output On An Example Case:

```
==6634== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6634== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6634== Using Valgrind-3.6.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6634== Command: ./a.out 100S.txt
==6634==
==6634== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6634==    at 0x400C13: checkonqueue (bfs.c:160)
==6634==    by 0x400B7F: BFS (bfs.c:142)
==6634==    by 0x40094A: main (bfs.c:103)
==6634==
==6634== Invalid write of size 4
==6634==    at 0x40096E: main (bfs.c:107)
==6634==  Address 0x4d00000041 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6634==
==6634==
==6634== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6634==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4D00000041
==6634==    at 0x40096E: main (bfs.c:107)
==6634==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6634==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6634==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6634==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6634==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
==6634==
==6634== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6634==     in use at exit: 3,448 bytes in 181 blocks
==6634==   total heap usage: 181 allocs, 0 frees, 3,448 bytes allocated
==6634==
==6634== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6634==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6634==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6634==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6634==    still reachable: 3,448 bytes in 181 blocks
==6634==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6634== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==6634== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==6634==
==6634== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6634== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==6634== ERROR SUMMARY: 16120 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

check on queue function:

```
int checkonqueue(int * q, int value)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i < max;i++)
    {
        if(q[i] == value)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

line 160 is the line of the if condition

Comment: You're not touching the value of `numberVertices` or re-allocating `vertexArray` anywhere in between?

Comment: I don't suppose numberVertices changed between calls? Seeing how `vertexArray` is allocated would go a long way to solving this problem as well.

Comment: Where is the segfault? Are you sure its `vertexArray[i].marked = 0;`

Comment: Have you tried Valgrind?  If so, what does it say?

Comment: No I'm not touching numberVertices at all, and not reallcoating vertexArray at all either. vertexArray is a user made data structure. `vertex vertexArray[numberVertices]` is how its declared.

Comment: @Austin According to my debugger (GDB) the segfault is being thrown at that line

Comment: as for Valgrind, I must admit I have no idea what that is currently

Comment: Can you upload more of the code, or is it too unwieldy?

Comment: @Austin Code is somewhat long, if you set up a chat (still kind of new to stackoverflow and don't know how) I'll post it there if you're willing to review it

Comment: Valgrind is a tool that will, among other things, tell you on what line a segfault occurs and, to an extent, why.  See http://valgrind.org/.

Comment: @1'' I have it on my system actually, and did not realize it. I have never used it though, and perhaps you can expedite my learning curve by examining its output? I'll update my post

Comment: Sure.  Which lines are 160 and 107?  Those are the two lines where bad stuff happens.

Comment: @1'' I misread my code. 160 is actually the if condition line `if(q[i] == value)`. 107 is still the original segfault spot though

Comment: Line 160 implies that some integers in the array q are not initialized.  I'm not sure whether this is related to the problem you're having, but you should fix it anyway.  The segfault is happening because you're writing past the end of the array vertexArray.  From the code you've given, I can't see a reason why this would happen.  Does numberVertices increase after you create vertexArray?

Comment: no it does not, but I will play around with my q array and initializing it all the way!