# Perhaps a memory issue when I reinitialize an array?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, initialization, valgrind

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reinitializing an Array is creating a segfault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214567/reinitializing-an-array-is-creating-a-segfault)

I am running bellman ford and BFS on an input of edges with a given weight in the format (vertexa, vertexb, weight). After each time I read in the newest edge, I run BFS (part of a research project).

It appears to work perfectly with small sets, vertex's of 8 to 10, but when I jump to the next sample data which involves sets of vertex's 100 or greater it fails and segfaults when I reinitialize...

At first I initialize it like this:

```
for(i=0;i<numberVertices;i++)
        {
                vertexArray[i].v = i+1;
                vertexArray[i].adj = NULL;
                vertexArray[i].marked = 0;
                if(i==0)
                {
                        vertexArray[i].weight = 0;
                }
                else{
                        vertexArray[i].weight = 10000;
                }
        }
```

After calling BFS I must reinitialize marked to 0 so that BFS will work again so I reinitiailize the array:

numberUseful += BFS(vertexArray, q, u);

```
            for(i=0;i<numberVertices;i++)
            {
                    vertexArray[i].marked = 0;
            }
```

and the line `vertexArray[i].marked = 0;` gives a segfault.

At anothers suggestion I ran valgrind with this program as well yielding:

```
==6634== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6634== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6634== Using Valgrind-3.6.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6634== Command: ./a.out 100S.txt
==6634==
==6634== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6634==    at 0x400C13: checkonqueue (bfs.c:160)
==6634==    by 0x400B7F: BFS (bfs.c:142)
==6634==    by 0x40094A: main (bfs.c:103)
==6634==
==6634== Invalid write of size 4
==6634==    at 0x40096E: main (bfs.c:107)
==6634==  Address 0x4d00000041 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6634==
==6634==
==6634== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6634==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4D00000041
==6634==    at 0x40096E: main (bfs.c:107)
==6634==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6634==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6634==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6634==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6634==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
==6634==
==6634== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6634==     in use at exit: 3,448 bytes in 181 blocks
==6634==   total heap usage: 181 allocs, 0 frees, 3,448 bytes allocated
==6634==
==6634== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6634==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6634==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6634==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6634==    still reachable: 3,448 bytes in 181 blocks
==6634==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6634== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==6634== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==6634==
==6634== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6634== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==6634== ERROR SUMMARY: 16120 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Which I am told gave me errors at the same line as my segfault (107) and at line 160 which is part of the checkonqueue function:

```
int checkonqueue(int * q, int value)
{
        int i = 0;
        for(i=0;i < max;i++)
        {
                if(q[i] == value)
                {
                        return 1;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Where `if(q[i] == value)` gave a memory issue so I'm told.

The reason I believe it may be a memory issue is due to the fact that it works with smaller sets (or so it seems!)

If you have any idea how to really use valgrind or can spot an error I'd be extremely grateful!

BFS:

```
while(front != -1)
{
    u = dequeue(q);
    if(vertexArray[u-1].adj != NULL)
    {
        adjacent = vertexArray[u-1].adj;
        vertexArray[u-1].marked = 1;


        while(adjacent != NULL)
        {
            v = adjacent->v;
            if(distance[vertexArray[v-1].v-1] > distance[vertexArray[u-1].v-1] + adjacent->edgeWeight)
            {
                distance[vertexArray[v-1].v-1] = distance[vertexArray[u-1].v-1] +adjacent->edgeWeight;
                success = 1;

            }

            int check = 0;
            check = checkonqueue(q, v);
            if(check == 0 && vertexArray[v-1].marked == 0)
            {
                enqueue(q, v);
            }
            adjacent = adjacent->next;
        }
    }
}
return success;
```

Comment: Smaller sets working is not conclusive proof you have issues with your RAM. Blue screens on your OS, on the other hand, are. More than likely, smaller sets are still walking on memory they shouldn't but what they're blasting isn't out of the address space that triggers a set-fault. That `.v` member of vertexArray being i+1 is useless, since it will always be (i+1) you can assume any vertexArray[i] has a `.v` of (i+1). Is there *anywhere* in your code that uses **that** value (`.v`) from a vertexArray entry as an index later into the same (or different) vertexArray array ?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, my post has been updated with my BFS code

Comment: All the indexes in the BFS code look right (considering I'm totally unfamiliar with the purpose, I just wanted to make sure no `.v` was used as a direct index into a vertexArray[]). The only other thing i can think of off the top of my head validating no `v` is *ever* pushed into the queue that is larger than the number of entries in vertexArray[], nor by the logic of this function, can it *ever* be zero. Just off-hand, where is the `distance[]` array defined, and more specifically, where is its *size* defined?

Comment: distance is globally defined and its size is hardcoded to 1000

Comment: is `max` defined as 1000 as well? (i.e. the maximum queue entries), and likewise the max vertexArray[] ceiling as well ?